# How to perform Johansen cointegration test iteratively for 2 variables taking some rows at a time?

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to test cointegration between two time series using Johansen Cointegration test. I want to perform the test incrementally, first 120 observations then leaving 1 at top and adding one at bottom for total 2250 observations. I want to automate this using a For loop, but the code is giving error. Please help.

```
library(urca)
x= BDICOM$BDI
y= BDICOM$Soybn
for(i in 1:2666){
A = x[i:i+120]; B = y[i:i+120]
jocot[i] = ca.jo(data.frame(A,B), type = "eigen", ecdet = "none",K = 2, spec = "longrun");i=i+1
}
```

Comment: please share a portion of your data `BDICOM`

Comment: Why `2666` if you have `2000` observations? It should be `2000-120`. Secondly you have to add parentheses in `[i:(i+120)]`.

Comment: And why you added `i=i+1`? `i` increments by itself. And did you initialise `jocot` vector?

Comment: How to share the data sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, but without sample of your data i can't be sure if it's correct:

```
library(urca)

x = BDICOM$BDI
y = BDICOM$Soybn

jocot <- vector('numeric', (2000-120))
for(i in 1:(2000-120)){
  A = x[i:(i+120)]
  B = y[i:(i+120)]
  jocot[i] = ca.jo(
    data.frame(A, B),
    type = "eigen",
    ecdet = "none",
    K = 2,
    spec = "longrun"
  )@teststat[2]
}
```

Comment: for(i in 1:(2250-120)){ + A = x[i:(i+120)] + B = y[i:(i+120)] + jocot[i] = ca.jo(data.frame(A, B), type = "eigen", ecdet = "none", K = 2, spec = "longrun") + } Error in jocot[i] <- ca.jo(data.frame(A, B), type = "eigen", ecdet = "none", : incompatible types (from S4 to double) in subassignment type fix

Comment: What value from the result of `ca.jo` function do you want to assign to the `jocot` vector?

Comment: The value of the test statistic

Comment: There are 2 values. `Unit Root / Cointegration Test`

Comment: cointegration test

Comment: So you have to add `@teststat[2]` after closing bracket of `ca.jo` function. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks but it is given following error:object of type 'S4' is not subsettable

Comment: Are you sure you've added `@teststat[2]` after `ca.jo`? Because `ca.jo(...)` function returns object of type `S4` but `ca.jo(...)@teststat[2]` returns a `double`.

Comment: Thanks ...it worked now..i had to reinitialize the jocot vector and then i ran the for code.. thanks a lot.